# Insert with complex ordered group counter

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

i try to create a complex SQL-Insert and i'm not sure to find the right buzzwords in the headline.

Ok here some data to expain my problem:

```
Date      Type
20160321  entry
20160322  entry
20160324  entry
20160325  delete
20160424  entry
20160425  entry
20160428  update
20160504  update
20160520  update
20160520  entry
```

Now i want to create groups by every change of the "type" in order of the date... so that at the end the following table would exists:

```
Date      Type    Group
20160321  entry   1
20160322  entry   1
20160324  entry   1
20160325  delete  2
20160424  entry   3
20160425  entry   3
20160428  update  4
20160504  update  4
20160520  update  4
20160520  entry   5
```

I tried out many things... with LEAD, LAG, FIRST_VALUE and later updates with row_number... but nothings works for this solution...
My problem is that the groups aren't defineable by the data itself... the groups arise in combination of the order and the value before...

I hope you understand my problem and are able to help me!

Comment: why update type was assigned 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT [Date], [Type], 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY min_Date) AS [Group]
FROM(
  SELECT [Date], [Type],
         MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Type], grp) AS min_Date
  FROM ( 
    SELECT [Date], [Type],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) - 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
    FROM mytable) AS t) AS s
ORDER BY [Date]
```

**Explanation:**

The innermost query:

```
SELECT [Date], [Type],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
FROM mytable
```

detects *islands* of consecutive records sharing the same `Type` value:

```
Date        Type    grp
========================
20160321    entry   0
20160322    entry   0
20160324    entry   0
20160325    delete  3
20160424    entry   1
20160425    entry   1
20160428    update  6
20160504    update  6
20160520    update  6
20160520    entry   4
```

The second level query uses MIN() OVER() so as to calculate the minimum `Date` value of each `Type` slice:

```
Date        Type    min_Date
============================
20160321    entry   20160321
20160322    entry   20160321
20160324    entry   20160321
20160325    delete  20160325
20160424    entry   20160424
20160425    entry   20160424
20160428    update  20160428
20160504    update  20160428
20160520    update  20160428
20160520    entry   20160520
```

The `Group` value can now be easily calculated by applying `DENSE_RANK` over the `min_Date` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extrem fast, great and complete answer! I thought i'm not so bad in sql but i wasn't able to find a solution! You save a lot of time of my life. thanks!